# Set UITableviewcell frame when tableview editing enable

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I am showing data in tableview and on editing it will be as in image. (i had allowed editing only for rows those were come after 4 th index).

[image]

Now i want to first four image cell frame as in the below reference image.

[image]

And i last i need the output as in the below reference image
[image].
If any suggestion or references for this problem.
Thanks

Comment: At last, i found solution the solution for this by making use of UITableView delegate method: - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 1):

For the first four cells, set a transparent image to **cell.imageView.image** This is not the perfect answer by any means but this will do the trick you want.

OR

For the four cells you can set the **cell.textLabel.text** by adding few spaces upfront like,

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"    YOUR TEXT";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.

I think you need the text alignment of all cells in same manner. If it is the case, I'll suggest three options:

1. When editing is pressed reload the tableView and add necessary spaces for first 3 rows
2. If you are using custom cells make another one for first three cells with exact spaces
3. If you are adding `UILabel` as subview of these cells change the frame

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following by creating two sections in the UITableView , where for the second view you can set the editing TRUE (not in first section) . Also pass the title for second section as "On My Pad" as shown in your reference image .

Hope it will help you !